# How to detect if point intersects with shape partially in view

Tags: javascript, css

The solution I'm after: to detect if a point falls within the red area below.

[image: red triangle in the top left corner with X and Y marked on the image]

Now the difficulty here is that the red area isn't an image, it's actually a div that has been rotated into position.

[image: rotated red box on a pink background]

Using JavaScript, how can I detect if a point lands in this area? And ideally in an efficient manner as this check might need to be called often and on slow devices.

CSS details: It has `position: absolute` on it, rotated `45 degrees` and has been positioned using `left: -135` and `top:0`.

My current approach has been to try and perform some calculation to determine where X intersects with the viewport, which will then give me Y (and I can calculate from there) but I have had no luck. Using `getBoundingClientRect()` on the element returns a square around the shape, but not of the shape itself.

How can this be done? Here is a small example (I want to detect if the top left corner of the `intersecting` element intersects with the red triangle):

```css
body {
    background: #ffd0ff;
    padding: 12px;
    margin: 0;
}

.sash {
    position: absolute;
    width: 270px;
    height: 80px;
    top: 0;
    left: -135px;
    background-color: #e10a0a;
    opacity: 0.5;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.intersection {
    background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
    padding: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="sash"></div>
<span class="intersection">
    Some intersecting div
</span>
```

Comment: So you have the pink area where the red area can move in right? And somewhere in this pink area you have a point where you have to check if it is on the red area? If so, what if the area is inside the red area but outside of the pink area (because the red area is partially outside the pink area)?

Comment: @Aaron3219 I have updated the JSFiddle with a better example (I want to detect if the top left corner of the `intersection` element intersects with the red triangle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the `document.elementFromPoint(x, y)` method, e.g.:

```js
function isPointInElement(x, y, selector) {

  let element = document.querySelector(selector);
  let elementFromPoint = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
  return element == elementFromPoint;
}

function isIntersecting(selector1, selector2) {

  let element1 = document.querySelector(selector1);
  let element1Coords = element1.getBoundingClientRect();
  return isPointInElement(element1Coords.top, element1Coords.left, selector2);
}

let isIntersectionInRedArea = isIntersecting('.intersection', 'div.sash');
console.log(`.intersection and div.sash are ${ isIntersectionInRedArea ? '' : 'not '}intersecting.`);


let isNonIntersectionInRedArea = isIntersecting('.non-intersection', 'div.sash');
console.log(`.non-intersection and div.sash are ${ isNonIntersectionInRedArea ? '' : 'not '}intersecting.`);
```

```css
body {
  background: #ffd0ff;
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 0;
}

.sash {
  position: absolute;
  width: 270px;
  height: 80px;
  top: 0;
  left: -135px;
  background-color: #e10a0a;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.intersection {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.non-intersection {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
  padding: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="sash"></div>
<span class="intersection">
    Some intersecting div
</span>
<span class="non-intersection">
    Non intersecting div
</span>
```

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, this is a good solution and works for my use case. While I won't be binding it to a `click` event, using `document.elementFromPoint` with `getBoundingClientRect()` does allow me to achieve what I am after. Thank you!

Comment: @DuncanOgle Added an example that uses `getBoundingClientRect()` as well.